# hidden submenu in nav bar displaying on hover but not dropping down

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript, so I apologize in advance if I waste anyone's time with a problem that may have a "duh" answer :-)

I am creating a navigation bar for a webpage. It starts off as an unordered list, and I am styling it to float the list items horizontally across the page.  That part works fine for me.

I started to work at incorporating an unordered list as a submenu of one of my original list items.  When I hover the mouse over the main list item, the submenu items appear, and when I mouse out, the submenu items disappear.  The problem is that when the submenu items appear, they display on top of the navigation link to the left, instead of breaking out and dropping down below the link that I am hovering over.  I tried setting the position to relative, but then it just shoved the submenu to the right.

I think the problem may be with my css.  If I do not apply the external style sheet, then things seem to work better.

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="DepartmentMembers.html" onMouseover="drop('menu')" onMouseout="hide('menu')">Department Members</a></li>
        <ul id="menu" style="display:none;position:absolute">
            <li><a href="BrianKendricks.html">Brian Kendricks</a></li>
            <li><a href="TimJones.html">Tim Jones</a></li>
            <li><a href="DavidKline.html">David Kline</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="SystemsUsed.html">Systems Used</a></li>
    <li><a href="SystemStatus.html">System Status</a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>

</ul>
```

My css is:

```
.nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-image:none;
    background-color: #004E98;
    display: block;
}

.nav a {
    color: white;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.nav li:a:hover {
    background-color: #093F6D;
}
```

And here is my javascript:

```
function drop(menu) {
    document.getElementById(menu).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(menu).style.position = 'relative';
}

function hide(menu) {
    document.getElementById(menu).style.display = 'none';
}
```

I would like to stick to using javascript, as the course that I am taking does not wish for me to incorporate things like JQuery at this time.

Thanks in advance for any assistance that you may offer in pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question exactly?  Hard to guess with so much code and no concise question.

Comment: Sorry not to be concise, and sorry for too much code.  I am looking for a way to get my submenus to drop down below the menu, rather than slide in as part of the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your submenu a child of the `<li>` they are under - instead of currently you have it a child of the overall `<ul>`.  Then you can give the parent item relative positioning, and the child list absolute positioning with top 100% (putting it under the parent item).

```js
function drop(menu) {
    document.getElementById(menu).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(menu) {
    document.getElementById(menu).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-image:none;
    background-color: #004E98;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.nav a {
    color: white;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.nav li:a:hover {
    background-color: #093F6D;
}

.dropmenu {
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 0;
}

.dropmenu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="DepartmentMembers.html" onMouseover="drop('menu')" onMouseout="hide('menu')">Department Members</a>
        <ul id="menu" class="dropmenu" style="display:none">
            <li><a href="BrianKendricks.html">Brian Kendricks</a></li>
            <li><a href="TimJones.html">Tim Jones</a></li>
            <li><a href="DavidKline.html">David Kline</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li><a href="SystemsUsed.html">Systems Used</a></li>
    <li><a href="SystemStatus.html">System Status</a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, MatthewG.  I will give this a try.  I'm sure I will be back soon to flag this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, MatthewG.  This helps a lot.  I especially appreciate not being made to feel dumb about not knowing what turned out to be a simple thing.  When you are learning something new, even simple things turn out to be daunting.  Now I need to work on getting that submenu to stick around long enough to click on it, and I suspect that will involve messing with a timer.  Have a great day!

Comment: I made some changes to incorporate a timer to keep the menu active so that I can click on links.  It worked well on my test page, but once I incorporated it onto one of my main pages it throws everything down when the dropdown appears.  I've heard that changing the position from absolute to relevant should help, but that totally breaks my dropdown and throws it way down to the bottom of the page, inaccessible.  Do you mind taking a look at this and telling me where I am going wrong?  https://jsfiddle.net/donfrankrice/sgu6nu5w/4/